# Кроссбраузерная верстка

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно сделать так, как показано на картинке.

[image]

HTML код:

```
<div id="rotate"></div>
```

CSS стили:

```
#rotate {
    width: 230px;
    height: 75px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
    background-color:#000000;
    position:absolute;
    left: -195px;
    top: 82px;
}
```

В хроме все выглядит отлично. А вот в опере и мозиле - коряво (даже очень). Так вот как сделать так, чтобы это поддерживали все браузеры. И можно ли обойтись без `position: absolute;` иначе, когда я меняю размер окна, все слетает. (( Заранее сердечно благодарен!

Comment: Картинка не грузится..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм, вовсе не кроссбраузерно получается - для IE на CSS'e вообще ни слова :), по мне так самый простой и кроссбраузерный способ сделать это - оставить картинкой и использовать тэг [`<map>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/map).

Однако, если вам все-таки не нравиться забавляться с картинкой, вот ссылка на статью "[Cross Browser CSS Transforms – even in IE](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/)" про трансформации на CSS.

Comment: Значит на бэкграунде изображения уже будут эти полоски, а затем с помощью map будут накладываться ссылки? Я правильно понял?)

Comment: Да, именно так)

Comment: спасибо) как попробую отпишусь)